# How to bend a path in Keynotes?

Tags: keynote, path

I can not find the 'curved path button' in the Build Inspector which allows me to curve a path.
Can anyone tell me where to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it in the **Build Inspector** under the **Action** *tab*.

[image: The Build Inspector] 
 [image: The Curved Path Button]

Comment: At my version the boxes beneath 'Path' were empty (no lines in it) so I did not realize what they were for. Thank you, ths was all I needed to know!